# Should I use integers for saving boolean values?

Tags: php, mysql

I have created the following drop down for my front-end webpage:

```
<select>
   <option value="All">All</option>
   <option value="carer">Carer</option>
   <option value="childminder">Childminder</option>
   <option value="children_socialcare">Children Social Care</option>
   <option value="creche">Creche</option>
</select>
```

I've set up the mysql database to have all the option values as fields:

```
Type=INT(1) Null=Yes; Default=Null
```

I have set these as integers as I'm copying in data from a word form where the select options are checkboxes.

mysql table:

```
mysql> family_support;
+---------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field   | Type        | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+---------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| carer   | int(1)      | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
+---------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
```

Although tideous is it okay to use integers in this way (not just for numeric values)?

Comment: show us the table description

Comment: How are the integers mapped to the drop down fields?

Comment: I don't see what the issue here is.  INTs are used for ID numbers (that have no numeric meaning) all the time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the questions is: Should I use integers for saving boolean values?

Yes you should. I suggest to use `TINYINT(1) NOT NULL`. Use the values 1 (TRUE/selected/checked) and 0 (FALSE/not selected/not checked).

In newer MySQL releases you can use the the field type `BOOL`/`BOOLEAN`, which is just an alias for `TINYINT(1)`.

See here: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/numeric-type-overview.html

Comment: Thanks, i've also changed the question. Apologies I need to do more homework.